# Add a new firebird-db user with acces to specific tables?

Tags: roles, firebird2.5

I need to create a new firebird-db user which has only access to 4 specific tables. Is there a way to do that?

http://www.destructor.de/firebird/gsec.htm isn't really helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The - third-party - gsec documentation you link does not provide information about granting rights on tables, because gsec is only for managing users in the security database. In Firebird, rights of users are managed in the individual databases using the `GRANT` (and `REVOKE`) statements (it is even possible to grant rights to users that do not exist (yet)). Be aware, Firebird 3 deprecated gsec, and since Firebird 2.5, it is recommended to use the SQL user management statements instead of gsec.

You need to create the user, and then give the user privileges to the tables you want. See the [Security](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security) chapter in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference.

> A regular, authenticated user has no privileges on any database object
> until they are explicitly granted, either to that individual user or
> to all users bundled as the user PUBLIC.

Specifically:

1. Create a user:

   ```sql
   create user <username> password '<password>';
   ```

   See also [`CREATE USER`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-auth-create-user); to create a user, you need to be either SYSDBA, or you need to have and the admin role in the security database, and the RDB$ADMIN role in the current database, and be logged in specifying the RDB$ADMIN role on connect.
2. Grant the necessary privileges to the user. For example to give SELECT privileges:

   ```sql
   grant select on table <tablename> to user <username>;
   ```

   To allow select, insert, update and delete:

   ```sql
   grant select, insert, update, delete on table <tablename> to user <username>;
   ```

   See also [`GRANT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-privs-grant); to grant permission to an object, you must be either SYSDBA, the owner of the object, be RDB$ADMIN in the current database, or have been granted the privilege(s) with the `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

When you need to grant the same set of rights to multiple users, it is better to grant rights to a role, and then grant that role to the users. However in Firebird 3 and earlier, to get the rights granted to a role, the user needs to explicitly specify that role on connect (Firebird 4 introduced *default* roles that are automatically applied).